# Certificate validation in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate, x509

i have to check a specific certificate. Unfortunately i don't have a clue how i can accomplish this. The certificate which i want to validate is signed by my own ca. I need to check the whole certificate-chain. The validation should be done within C#.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: any reason you don't install the certificate and the root cert into the cert store ?

Comment: The root cert is already installed. But i need to verify the certificate against a specific one. A verification against the whole store is unwished.

Comment: this is a very sensitive area and some bug/mishandling in self-implementing the whole check might lead to a serious security problem... IMHO "unwished" is not good enough as a reason to warrant a higher risk...

Comment: I'm running this in context of wcf, this means that the authentication is already provided through the framework. Now i have to realize the authentication. I'm getting the validation Callback by WCF. Unfortunately i don't know how to check whether the provided certificate is signed by my own CA or not... I don't want to re-implemenent existing mechanisms, i want to use them.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do... the framework already verifies the cert if it is in the cert store - no need to implement anything yourself... anyway, see my answer below on how to go about custom cert validation...

Comment: I'm using client authentication by certificate in combiation with wcf's transport security. Unfortunately every client that is signed from a valid CA is able to connect to my service. The reason for this behaviour is, that wcf is checking the whole Trusted-CA-Store if there is any valid CA that signed the provided certificate. My application needs to restrict the access only to those clients which were signed by my own ca. Thats the reason why i want to introduce a custom validation.

Comment: that can be accomplished with pure configuration - just create a "private cert store" on the server, put all the allowed clients certs in there and configure WCF to use that store only for validation...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8260/discussion-between-user1168876-and-yahia)

Answer (score 5):

IF you want to do everything including verification of the chain in code then you need to [implement "custom validation" and integrate that into the WCF Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx):

```
Client.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
              X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
Client.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator =
    new MyCertificateValidator();
```

For validating the chain yourself you should take a look at [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx) and [X509Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx) - to get an idea how such a chain verification could be implemented take a look at [Mono's implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Security/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs.htm) of the `Verify`... basically you use the `Find` method to search a [X509Certificate2Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.aspx) for the parent and so on... verification criteria with a custom validation is up to you (valid signature, not expired...).

some reference links at MSDN:

- [X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509servicecertificateauthentication.certificatevalidationmode.aspx)
- [X509CertificateValidator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.aspx)
- [How to: Create a Service that Employs a Custom Certificate Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx)